# Simple javascript conditions

Tags: javascript

I have a simple javascript conditions. I'm new to javascript, so I'm struggling a lot to solve this. Would be greatful if anyone can help me figuring this out.

I want to display a div in specific time period. In all other cases the div should not be visible.

```js
var currentdate = new Date();
var d1=new Date("2021-05-18, 02:35:00"); 
var d2=new Date("2021-05-18, 02:36:00");


if((currentdate>=d1)&&(currentdate<=d2)) 
{  
document.getElementById("timer").style.display = "block";  
}

else 
{  
document.getElementById("timer").style.display = "none";  
}
```

```css
#timer{
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            background:#ff934f;
            }
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Comment: What is wrong with what you have?

Comment: Should the block appear and disappear at those specified times while the user keeps the page open (sudden automatic popup and disappearance), or should it simply be on the page when the user loads the page during the specified time and then stay there, regardless of how long the user keeps the page open?

Comment: Yes. It should appear and disppear between those specified time. The timer box should not appear if the time doesn't match. If it matches it should show and disappear after 60 seconds of time. (the time period)

Answer (score 0):

You should learn how to debug your code. Either by adding "debugging;" to your code, or by adding breakpoints in the console (opens by pressing F12).

I will try to print `console.log(1 < currentdate);` and `console.log(d1 < currentdate)`. One of them should return `true`, right?

```js
var currentdate = new Date();
var d1 = new Date("2021-05-18, 02:35:00");
var d2 = new Date("2021-05-18, 02:36:00");


console.log(d1 < currentdate); // false
console.log(d1 > currentdate); // false

if ((currentdate >= d1) && (currentdate <= d2)) {
  document.getElementById("timer").style.display = "block";
} else {
  document.getElementById("timer").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#timer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ff934f;
}
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>
```

No, both return false. Why?

Lets print the `d1` date variable.

```js
var currentdate = new Date();
var d1 = new Date("2021-05-18, 02:35:00");
var d2 = new Date("2021-05-18, 02:36:00");


console.log("d1", d1); // null

if ((currentdate >= d1) && (currentdate <= d2)) {
  document.getElementById("timer").style.display = "block";
} else {
  document.getElementById("timer").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#timer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ff934f;
}
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>
```

It outputs `null`, so the declaration to create that date is wrong. In order to create a date from a string, you can use [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse). But that will also result in null, because you need to remove the comma from the date string: `2021-05-18 02:35:00` (no comma between date and time).

```js
var currentdate = new Date();
var d1 = Date.parse("2021-05-18 02:35:00");
var d2 = Date.parse("2021-05-18 02:36:00");


console.log("d1", d1); // 1621298100000

console.log("currentdate is newer:", currentdate > d1) // true
console.log("currentdate is older:", currentdate < d1) // false

if ((currentdate >= d1) && (currentdate <= d2)) {
  document.getElementById("timer").style.display = "block";
} else {
  document.getElementById("timer").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#timer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ff934f;
}
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Would it result in the same thing if we just removed the comma from `new Date("2021-05-18, 02:35:00")?

```js
var currentdate = new Date();
var d1 = new Date("2021-05-18 02:35:00");
var d2 = new Date("2021-05-18 02:36:00");


console.log("d1", d1); // 2021-05-18T00:35:00.000Z

console.log("currentdate is newer:", currentdate > d1) // true
console.log("currentdate is older:", currentdate < d1) // false

if ((currentdate >= d1) && (currentdate <= d2)) {
  document.getElementById("timer").style.display = "block";
} else {
  document.getElementById("timer").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#timer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ff934f;
}
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Comment: It might be my locale or browser (Chrome 90.0.4430.212 (Official Build) (64-bit)), but for me [it parses fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJOAX.png).

Answer (score -1):

Try this perhaps? That way you'll have everything as unix timestamps.

```js
var currentdate = Date.now();
var d1 = new Date("2021-05-18, 02:35:00").getTime();
var d2 = new Date("2021-05-18, 02:36:00").getTime();
```

Comment: Because the questioner is new in Javascript, you should add some explaination.

Comment: `Date` objects are comparable without `getTime`…